# Finding vector direction using Optical Flow in OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, opticalflow

I am struggling (and trying to learn) with understanding the concept of using the Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow function in OpenCV to find the directional movement of the 'good points to track'. I've been told I need to calculate the direction of vectors from the `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` function.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
namedWindow('OptFlow', cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# params for corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                   qualityLevel = 0.3,
                   minDistance = 7,
                   blockSize = 7 )

# LK params
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
              maxLevel = 2,
              criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT,
10, 0.03))

# Create some random colors
color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))

# Take first frame and find corners in it
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)

while(1):
ret,frame = cap.read()
frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# calculate optical flow
p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None,    **lk_params)

# Select good points
good_new = p1[st==1]
good_old = p0[st==1]

cv2.imshow('OptFlow',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

# update prev frame with new
old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

The code is from a tutorial I have been following as I am quite new to programming and Python. How would I find the directional movement so I could output a (-1) for movement to left, (0) for no movement and (1) for movement to the right from the optical flow calculation?

Thanks

Comment: If `good_new` is the new position and `good_old` the old position, isn't the direction of motion of the points simply `good_new-good_old` (maybe with normalization) ? Or do you mean something else by "the directional movement of the good points to track" ?

Comment: I am currently printing out to screen the good_new - good_old value and I am getting what seems to be an array that contains two separate values. They are a float type that constantly keep changing between -4 or so to about 4. Where there is minimal movement it is actually on 0. I may be close to what I need. Could you explain what the process of normalization does? Thanks

Comment: Well `good_new-good_old` is the set of vectors from the old points to the new ones. If you just want a direction, you may want to divide these vectors by their norm so that they all have a norm of 1.

Comment: Of course, you would need to be careful when normalizing a vector whose norm is close to zero.

Comment: can direction be inferred from the sign of difference between new and old points?If it is negative, it is in r-l direction and vice versa?